# How can an IAM role be restricted to gain higher permission than it itself is allowed, through role chaining?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a role named `ThisRole` with following `deny` permissions:

```
        {
            "Sid": "DenyPolicies",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AddUserToGroup",
                "iam:AttachGroupPolicy",
                "iam:AttachUserPolicy",
                "iam:CreateGroup",
                "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
                "iam:CreateUser",
                "iam:DeleteUser",
                "iam:DeleteLoginProfile",
                "iam:DeleteAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteGroup",
                "iam:DeleteGroupPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:DeleteUserPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:DetachGroupPolicy",
                "iam:DetachUserPolicy",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:RemoveUserFromGroup",
                "iam:UpdateGroup",
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

And following `allow` permissions:

```
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
```

I do want `ThisRole` to create new roles, create new and update existing IAM policies. Which is why `iam:CreateRole` and the likes are not denied. But this leaves the back door open for this role to:

1. Create a new role (lets say `NewRole`).
2. Allow this `NewRole` all the permissions itself is denied upon.
3. Assume this `NewRole` (role chaining).
4. Execute permissions that are otherwise denied for `ThisRole`.

What is the best way to allow `ThisRole` to create new roles/policies, modify existing roles/policies or assume another role but only within the limits of what it itself is allowed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best option is to use **Permissions Boundary**.

In this way you will allow them to create roles but they will be forced to use the permissions boundary you define, restricting them on what they can do.

Two links below will explain you more:

- [Permissions Boundaries for IAM Entities - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html)
- [Delegate permission management to developers by using IAM permissions boundaries | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/delegate-permission-management-to-developers-using-iam-permissions-boundaries/)

Comment: Thank you!
Yes, `iam:PermissionsBoundary` is what I was looking for.